# Htaccess: Redirect only files in public directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I currently have a `.htaccess` file that redirects[L] all requests to a `router.php`.

How can I make it redirect only URLS not heading to the `public` directory

That is,
`example.com/hello` will redirect to `router.php`

But   `example.com/public/app.css` and `example.com/public` should not be redirected at all.

This is my .htaccess file:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a condition to only rewrite when it doesn't have a `public` after the URI like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php [QSA,L]
```